# VS2017 - Template Core projects do not start

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I am using the most updated version of VS 2017 (version 15.2 - 26430.6-  release) and I am trying to use the ASP.Net Core templates.

I tried ASP.Net Core Web Application (.NET Core) both with ASP.NET Core 1.0 and 1.1 for the Empty and the Web Application templates and I always get the following when I try to run it:

```
code:-32000
message:No script for id: 31
The program '[8268] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -2147450749 (0x80008083).
The program '[6432] chrome.exe: WebKit' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
The program '[8656] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I have checked my .NET Core and I have the latest SDK plus the latest LTS and Current installations.
Even a simple .NET Core console app can not be launched...

I also tried some solutions [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1719) but nothing.

Any advices as it gets really frustrating.

Cheers

Sylvain

Answer (score 0):

OK after making several tests, it seems that the new templates are based on Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.2 which prevents the application to launch correctly.

If I add in my .csproj file:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>1.1.1</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

instead of

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>        
  </PropertyGroup>
```

It works.

I also have to remove the Nuget package named Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.codegeneration.Design 1.1.1 which relies on the Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.2.

Would it be a bug with 1.1.2 or a misuse in the templates?

Thanks

Sylvain